# speed up canvas's getImageData

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to extract chunks of pixels from the canvas and process them. Currently I am calling `getImageData` multiple times in nested loops.

```
_getBinaryStringFromCanvas(canvas) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  let { xMaxBlock, yMaxBlock, blockSize } = this.metrics;
  let results = '';
  for (let y = 0; y < yMaxBlock; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < xMaxBlock; x++) {
      let data = ctx.getImageData(x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
      let digit = this._somehowProcessTheData(data);
      binaryString += digit;
    }
  }
  return binaryString;
}
```

This is very slow as xMaxBlock and yMaxBlock can be pretty big. Ideally, I would want to do something like this -

```
_getChunkFromCache(cache, x, y, width, height){
  // need help implementing this function
}

_getBinaryStringFromCanvas(canvas) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  let { xMaxBlock, yMaxBlock, blockSize } = this.metrics;
  let results = '';
  let cache = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, xMaxBlock * blockSize, yMaxBlock * blockSize);
  for (let y = 0; y < yMaxBlock; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < xMaxBlock; x++) {
      let data = this._getChunkFromCache(cache, x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
      let digit = this._somehowProcessTheData(data);
      binaryString += digit;
    }
  }
  return binaryString;
}
```

But I can't seem to comprehend the logic required to address the region specified by x, y, width, height in the flat array returned
by `getImageData`.

Any help implementing `_getChunkFromCache` is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Don`t copy, index the array directly.

Getting a subsection of the original data array will need to be a copy as type arrays (The array in [`ImageData.data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) is a typed array [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray)) are only one dimensional and can not index a 2D section of another array. Creating a copy will only add more work and increase memory usage, slowing your app even further.

Your best option is for the `somehowProcessTheData` function to work directly with the image data and just index the array to the bounds you supply.

```
function somehowProcessTheData(imageData, x, y, w, h){
    var i,j;
    var result = ""; 
    var r,g,b,a;
    const data = imageData.data;

    for(j = 0; j < h; j++){
        var idx = (x + (y + j) * imageData.width) * 4;  // get left most byte index for row at y + j
        for(i = 0; i < w; i++){
             r = data[idx ++];
             g = data[idx ++];
             b = data[idx ++];
             a = data[idx ++];
             // do the processing
        }
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Or

```
function somehowProcessTheData(imageData, x, y, w, h){
    var i,j;
    var result = ""; 
    const data = imageData.data;

    for(j = 0; j < h; j++){
        var idx = (x + (y + j) * imageData.width) * 4;  
        for(i = 0; i < w; i++){
             // get the red green blue values
             var blah = data[idx] + data[idx + 1] + data[idx + 2];
             // do the processing
             // ...
             // increment the index to the next pixel.
             idx += 4;

        }
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Then in the calling loop

```
 let data = this.processTheData(cache, x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. You're a lifesaver. May I credit you in my application when it is released?

Comment: @EntangledMess If you wish to credit anyone, credit Stackoverflow. What I did was little effort, but they provide help to many via their service, which is a lot of ongoing effort by many.

Comment: @EntangledMess, App at?

Answer (score 3):

You can cache the whole area you're working on.
It's still slow but hopefully you won't need to do it often.
Below is an example to get an int for each pixel instead of 4 bytes.

```
const pixels = new Int32Array(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data.buffer)
pixels[x + y * w]
```

Comment: If you can, try using WebAssembly. It's fast and I use it to get really quick color blending on my program!